No service for type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Abstractions.IMediaFileTextExtractor' has been registered
Upgrade to 10.3.1. Any clue where and what to look?
Error:
No service for type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Abstractions.IMediaFileTextExtractor' has been registered.

Stack trace:
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Abstractions.IMediaFileTextExtractor' has been registered.]
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) +311
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider) +51
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentExtraction.Common.DefaultMediaItemTextExtractor..ctor() +33

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +387
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type) +109
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor.CreateExtractorImplicitly() +97
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor.Initialize(XmlNode configurationNode) +37

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +313
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters) +119
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DocumentBuilderOptions.CreateComputedIndexField(String fieldName, XmlNode configNode) +364
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions.AddComputedIndexField(XmlNode configNode) +80


were you able to solve the issue with the below suggestion. Let me know in case you are facing any issues.

Dependency for IMediaFileTextExtractor is resolved using the below configuration inside the App_Config/Sitecore/ContentSearch/Sitecore.ContentSearch.config file.
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <services>
       <configurator type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.DependencyInjection.ContentSearchConfigurator, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
    </services>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Can you check if above ContentSearchConfigurator is registered inside the config file. This configurator is responsible for injecting the object of IMediaFileTextExtractor interface.

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

If you search for IMediaFileTextExtractor in a working Sitecore 10.3.1 solution, the following three DLLs show in the result:

Sitecore.ContentSearch
Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentExtraction
Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider

If you decompile and search within each of those DLL using something like ILSpy, you can see the following:
Sitecore.ContentSearch
You can see the interface is defined here: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Abstractions.IMediaFileTextExtractor
Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentExtraction
This DLL has a reference to an obsolete version of the interface Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentExtraction.IMediaFileTextExtractor
Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider
This DLL defines a Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.ContentExtraction.SolrCellMediaFileTextExtractor which implements IMediaFileTextExtractor
Therefore, I would suggest that you are missing some config relating to SOLR, or you have somehow have the wrong file version of Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider. Please double check the properties of the DLL and ensure it has file version 10.1.11.6478 which is what I believe ships with Sitecore 10.3.1.
UPDATE
Upon seeing ckhannas answer, I can see the ContentServicesConfigurator actually creates an instance of Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentExtraction.DefaultMediaFileTextExtractor which implements the interface as well:
private static IMediaFileTextExtractor CreateMediaFileTextExtractor()
{
    return Factory.CreateObject("contentSearch/indexConfigurations/contentExtraction/mediaFileTextExtractor", assert: true) as IMediaFileTextExtractor;
}

Most likely thats the culprit. Still worth checking the file versions though.
